# Find the argument of $ \frac{-1 + \sqrt3 i}{2+2i} $

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I rewrite equation $ \frac{-1 + \sqrt3 i}{2+2i} $ as $$ \frac{ \sqrt3 - 1}{4} + \frac{ \sqrt3 + 1}{4} i  $$ using the conjugacy technique.

And set forward to find the argument of this complex function.
I'm assuming the argument is the angle between the positive real-axis and the line?

I do this by trying to calculate: 
$$ \mathbf{cos}^{-1}  \frac{ \sqrt3 + 1}{\sqrt3 - 1} $$

But my calculator doesn't seem to understand what I'm saying. Is this ratio just totally wrong?

Help please

Comment: Use $\tan^{-1}$.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith *facepalm* It's 4 in the morning where I am. I guess I needed to write something stupid on the internet to realize I've been up too long! Thank you

Comment: BTW, the quantity from which you want to calculate the $\;arccos\;$ is greater than $\;1\;$, so no wonder your calculator writes ERROR: that function's defined *only* for value in $\;[-1,1]\;$ ...

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith : I'm wondering why you're not mentioning that one can subtract arguments.  That seems like the main thing one needs to be aware of here.

Comment: @Siyanda That's what I thought.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I didn't think of it.  But that's a good point.  I was merely trying to help the OP realize they had made an easy mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You can subtract arguments.  The argument of $-1+\sqrt{3}\,i$ is an angle in the second quadrant whose tangent is $\sqrt{3}/(-1)$, so it is $2\pi/3$ or $120^\circ$.  The argument of $2+2i$ is an angle in the first quadrant whose tangent is $2/2$ so it is $\pi/4$ or $45^\circ$.

Subtracting, you get $120^\circ-45^\circ$ or $2\pi/2 - \pi/4$.

Answer (score 1):

using eulers equation$$e^{i\theta} =\cos \theta+i\sin \theta$$the given expression can be written as $$\frac{\frac{-1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i}{1+i}$$which is$$\frac{e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}}{ e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}}$$you get the resulting arguement$\frac{5\pi}{12}$